# Switching A tags order using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

lets say i have five a tags

```
<a id = "A" class = "Home">Home</a>
<a id = "B" class = "Maps">Maps</a>
<a id = "C" class = "Plans">Plans</a>
<a id = "D" class = "Community">Community</a>
<a id = "E" class = "Comments">Comments</a>
```

i would like sort the elements to any position such as:

```
<a id = "E" class = "Comments">Comments</a>
<a id = "D" class = "Community">Community</a>
<a id = "C" class = "Plans">Plans</a>
<a id = "A" class = "Home">Home</a>
<a id = "B" class = "Maps">Maps</a>
```

using Jquery i thought to use the deatch() then after() however I can't figure out the correct way to implement them.

here what i tried

```
var b = document.getElementById("B");
var c = document.getElementById("C");
$("a").detach("#B");
$("c").after(b);
```

lmk if u can help. 
THANKS!

Comment: use `$(a)`? have you tried

Comment: Can you please provide more information about what do you mean by " sorting into any position" ?  you want to sort elements? or change position by drag and drop etc? its a dynamic behavior or you only want to make it to look another way one time

Comment: rearrange them any position like if  A B C D E to E D C B A or C D B A

Comment: found out i should just use after

Comment: it simply moves the a tag where i want without needing to remove() it first

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest to simply use Flexbox `order` property instead of cut/paste elements

```js
$("#A").css("order", "4");
$("#B").css("order", "5");
$("#C").css("order", "3");
$("#D").css("order", "2");
$("#E").css("order", "1");
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}
div a {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <a id = "A" class = "Home">Home</a>
  <a id = "B" class = "Maps">Maps</a>
  <a id = "C" class = "Plans">Plans</a>
  <a id = "D" class = "Community">Community</a>
  <a id = "E" class = "Comments">Comments</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.insertAfter` will move it to whatever you want.

ALSO, in case you wonder why the white space is gone, it is because

> Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements
>
> A series of inline-block elements formatted like you normally format HTML will have spaces in between them.
>
> REF: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/
>
> Example below:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none
}

li {
  background: slategrey;
  display: inline-block;
  /* inline block hack for IE 6&7 */
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  padding: 4px;
  color: white
}

ul.white-space-fix li {
  margin-right: -4px;
}

ul.zero-size {
  font-size: 0px;
}
ul.zero-size li {
  font-size: 16px;
}

ul.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
```

```html
<h1>Inline-block / white-space bug</h1>
original...
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>

fixed by funky code formatting...
<ul>
  <li>
   one</li><li>
   two</li><li>
   three</li>
</ul>

fixed by adding html comments...
<ul>
  <li>one</li><!--
  --><li>two</li><!--
  --><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('#C').insertAfter($('#E'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="A" class="Home">Home</a><a id="B" class="Maps">Maps</a><a id="C" class="Plans">Plans</a><a id="D" class="Community">Community</a><a id="E" class="Comments">Comments</a>
```

Comment: beat me on timing :)

Comment: thanks man. now i have to make a space between comments and plans tho

Comment: @EthanE oh the space is because the tags, it is an issues with HTML incase you don't know yet

Comment: @EthanE if you end your tag and in new line started a new tag, you will have a 2px space between elements (inline elements), sometimes this is annoying and most people just didn't notice that.

Comment: @EthanE take 2mins reading this one, would be really helpful https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```js
$('.moveA').click(function() {
  $('#A').insertAfter($('#E'));
});
```

```css
a {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id = "A" class = "Home button is-success">Home</a>
<a id = "B" class = "Maps button is-success">Maps</a>
<a id = "C" class = "Plans button is-success">Plans</a>
<a id = "D" class = "Community button is-success">Community</a>
<a id = "E" class = "Comments button is-success">Comments</a>
<a class="moveA button is-success">move link A to bottom</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this, if you want to move the element with id="B" after the element with id="C",

```
$("#B").insertAfter("#C");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a method . please take a look if you like this
Your Html can be this

```
<div id="container">
    <a id = "A" class = "Home">Home</a>
    <a id = "B" class = "Maps">Maps</a>
    <a id = "C" class = "Plans">Plans</a>
    <a id = "D" class = "Community">Community</a>
    <a id = "E" class = "Comments">Comments</a>
</div>
```

and your JS method can look like this

```
 var container = $('#container');
 function changeOrder(positions){
    positions = positions.split(',');
    for(var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++){
        container.append($('#'+positions[i]));
        container.append(' ');
    }
 }
```

then you can re-order them any time you call the method with desired order.

```
changeOrder("C,D,E,B,A");
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this out! Just change the string `$link_order` to your desired order of elements

```js
$link_order = "ECDBA"; //How you want your links to be ordered

for($i = 0; $i < $link_order.length; $i++){
  $element = "#" + $link_order[$i];
  $_temp = $($element); //Temporarily save the element
  $($element).remove(); //Remove the element
  $("#links").append($_temp); //Reinsert the element in the correct order
  $("#links").append(" "); //Space
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="links">
  <a id = "A" class = "Home">Home</a>
  <a id = "B" class = "Maps">Maps</a>
  <a id = "C" class = "Plans">Plans</a>
  <a id = "D" class = "Community">Community</a>
  <a id = "E" class = "Comments">Comments</a>
</div>
```